# Unable to install flash plugin in ubuntu?

Tags: flash, plugins

I need to install flashplugin in all the ubuntu systems. So i have downloaded the flashplugin via wget `wget http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flashplugin_11.2.202.228.orig.tar.gz`. The file got downloaded and i have moved the file to /var/www/ using wget i have downloaded this file on all the client systems. On executing i am getting the below error.. Please help me on fixing this error..

#### Error:

`root@user219:~# ./adobe-flashplugin_11.2.202.228.orig.tar.gz`
`-bash: ./adobe-flashplugin_11.2.202.228.orig.tar.gz: cannot execute binary file`

#### Update 1:

`I can see the automated install when runs "apt-get install flashplugin-installer" follows these steps..`

``` Downloading...
--2012-07-24 01:17:13--  http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flashplugin_11.2.202.228.orig.tar.gz
Resolving archive.canonical.com... 91.189.92.150, 91.189.92.191
Connecting to archive.canonical.com|91.189.92.150|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 14133169 (13M) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: ``./adobe-flashplugin_11.2.202.228.orig.tar.gz' ```

```
 0K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 22%  343K 31s
```

`3072K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 44%  508K 19s`
`6144K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 66%  479K 11s`
 `9216K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 89%  400K 4s`
`12288K ........ ........ .......                            100%  356K=33s`

`2012-07-24 01:17:47 (414 KB/s) - ./adobe-flashplugin_11.2.202.228.orig.tar.gz' saved [14133169/14133169]`

`Download done.`
`Flash Plugin installed.`

Comment: You can't execute the archive file. You need to first extract the contents, and then there will likely be a shell script that you can execute within the extracted directory.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to install adobe flash is to install it on each system from the Ubuntu multiverse repository. `flashplugin-installer` is the package name. The ubuntu-restricted-extras meta package depends (indirectly) on either it or adobe-flashplugin.

To clear up possible confusion about what you see when you installed the package above, the .deb file contains an installer shell script. Most of the real work is done in the /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/install-plugin the .deb package installs:

```
 #!/bin/sh

 set -e

 flash_tarball="$1"

 FILENAME=adobe-flashplugin.tar.gz

 fp_exit_with_error() {
     echo $1
     echo "The Flash plugin is NOT installed."
     exit 1
 }

 cd /var/cache/flashplugin-installer

 echo "Installing from local file $flash_tarball"
 cp -f -p "$flash_tarball" ${FILENAME}_TEMP
 mv -f ${FILENAME}_TEMP $FILENAME

 rm -rf adobe_flashplugin*/

 # unpacking and checking the plugin
 tar xzf $FILENAME || fp_exit_with_error "cannot unpack plugin"

 install -m 644 adobe-flashplugin*/i386/libflashplayer.so /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/
 rm -rf adobe-flashplugin*

 echo "Flash Plugin installed."

 update-alternatives --quiet --install "/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/flashplugin-alternative.so" "mozilla-flashplugin" /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so 50

 exit 0
```

You can see that the file is untarred and moved to /usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/i386/libflashplayer.so and then update-alternatives is used to make this a possible mozilla flashplugin.

Again, it's best to have all of the protection and automation of using the apt package installation system do the work rather than trying to do it yourself, if you can.

Comment: Can i use this script to install flash plugin?? I have already downloaded `adobe-flashplugin_11.2.202.228.orig.tar.gz'`

Comment: As I noted above, I would use the automated processes to install and keep it up-to-date. I suppose you can try it if you want, however.

Comment: I am getting this error on running the above script...`root@user254:~# bash flashplugin.sh`
`flashplugin.sh: line 15: cd: /var/cache/flashplugin-installer: No such file or directory`

Comment: Right, the directory is installed by the flashplugin-installer package and is owned by root. The script needs to be passed the name of the file you downloaded, as well.

Comment: The downloaded file name is `adobe-flashplugin_11.2.202.228.orig.tar.gz` in script where do i mention???

Comment: I'm gonna say the same: do it using apt-get. It's fast, secure and easy. Downloading the file, uncompressing it and copying it to a folder is slower, and can get you in trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Flash is part of the package `ubuntu-restricted-extras` in the repository.

More info about `ubuntu-restricted-extras` and what is contains:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats